# What is the difference between EOF and ordinary integer?

Tags: c, char, eof

below is the code

**Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main(void)
{
    int ch;

    while((ch = getchar()) != 'h')
        putchar(ch);


    return 0;
}
```

**Question :**

1.)So as usual i just run this code , due to curiosity when the program prompt for input , i insert `^z(CTRL + Z)` which is `EOF (Windows 7 Command Prompt)` , but all i get is infinite looping of character printing.

2.)From the code , my logic is that since i input `^z` to the program , it'll just evaluate the logic `(ch = getchar()) != 'h'` and value `true` or `1` will be returned and character `^z` will be printed out.But instead different result is yield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press `^Z`, the program notices the input stream was closed, but you keep on using `getchar()`, so you get `EOF`. This loops infinitely, since you can't input `'h'` anymore. Note that ***only*** `'h'` (not `'A'`, not `^M`, and also not `^Z`) can **stop** the program, since **you loop if you don't get a 'h'**.

In other words, if you want to stop if anything else but `'h'` is entered, then do

```
do
{
    ch = getchar();
    putchar(ch);
} while (ch == 'h');
```

Answer (score 1):

EOF is typically defined as -1 (but it's implementation specific). When you call putchar(-1), it will be converted to unsigned char, and become the value 255, which is then output (ÿ unless I'm mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

EOF *is* an integer with an implementation-defined negative value. Your code loops indefinitely because only entering 'h' would make it finish. But once it reads EOF, which is `!= 'h'`, it enters an infinite loop because the standard input is closed and there is nothing that can make it return anything else.